# docker-compose throws error with getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

## background:

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.
I'm trying to build images using docker-compose.

This is my `docker-compose` file

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:     
    web:
        build: ./frontend
        network_mode: "host"
        ports: 
            - 3000:3000
    api:
        build: ./backend
        network_mode: "host"
        ports: 
            - 3001:3001
        environment: 
            DB_URL: mongodb://db/foo-app
    db:
        image: mongo:4.0-xenial
        ports: 
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - foo-app-data:/data/db

volumes:
    foo-app-data:
```

And below are my two `Dockerfile` files:

```sh
# ./backend file

FROM node:16.3.0-alpine3.13

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
WORKDIR /app

USER root
COPY package*.json ./

# --- debug try
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
# ---

RUN npm install
COPY . . 
RUN chown app:app /app
USER app

EXPOSE 3001 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```sh
# ./frontend file

FROM node:16.3.0-alpine3.13

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
WORKDIR /app

USER root
COPY package*.json ./

# --- debug try
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
# ---

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN chown app:app /app
USER app

EXPOSE 3000 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

## error:

When I run `docker-compose build`, the below error is thrown:

```
Step 8/14 : RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
 ---> Running in ce221adb18f6
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-06-13T10_19_13_600Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g @angular/cli' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

## what i have tried so far:

when I was building each docker file manually, I was getting the same error, until I used the `--network=host`. It means, when I build the images with `docker build --network=host`, it works fine. So I tried to add `network_mode= "host"` to my docker-compose file but it doesn't solve the issue.

and for God's sake, **read this before marking this question as duplicate**:

1. this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158939/getaddrinfo-eai-again-registry-npmjs-org80) propose a solution for docker and not docker compose. When I `ping registry.npmjs.org`, the connection works fine.
2. this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399905/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again-docker-nginx) propose to `docker-compose up`, which will throw the exact same error as I have here.
3. this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515203/docker-npm-install-error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-registry-npmjs-org-registry-npmj) doens't work, i have already restarted docker multiple times. And on top of that, I clean all docker images after the error is thrown to make sure the next time I build, nothing is used from the cache.
4. this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592908/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-registry-npmjs-org-registry-npmjs-org443) doesn't work either. I tried to (1) remove the proxies from the npm config, and also add the additional lines `npm cache clean --force` and `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` in my Dockerfile. Nothing works.
5. this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56666699/npm-err-request-to-https-registry-npmjs-org-ngx-pagination-failed-reason-ge) not only doesn't solve the problem, but also it doesn't really explain well the reason why the solution is being proposed.
6. and this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112049/error-getaddrinfo-eai-again-api-spotify-com443) i don't even know how this answer is allowed on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **network_mode** with **host** value, you can't mix it with port mapping: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

Then, or you change your network_mode to bridge or you drop your port mapping for each service.

Answer (score 0):

Add following Variable to .zshrc file in mac

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```